# Passing args to subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

Need to call grep from python
grep command: `grep -B 5 -A 5 "make.*Error|Error-" file`

Tried various combinations of escaping the regex  make it work with subprocess.Popen

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['grep','-B 5', '-A 5', r'"make.*Error|Error-"', file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Am I missing some sort of escape characters to pass that regex correctly to grep?

Appreciate the help

Comment: You don't need the double quotes.  The double quotes in the bash command are there to make sure the phrase is passed as a single parameter.  You're already doing that with Popen.

Comment: @TimRoberts - I had tried like this. Doesn't work.  proc = subprocess.Popen(['grep','-B 5', '-A 5', 'make.*Error|Error-' , 'file.log'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

Answer (score 0):

changed grep to egrep and used the following format to pass regex and it worked!

proc = subprocess.Popen(['egrep','-C 5', r"Error-|make.*Error" , 'file.log'],  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)